# Python subprocess.call arguments not being detected

Tags: python

I have a script whichs shells out to use the Hadoop CLI to upload a file to HDFS

Here is the snippet:

```
def hdfs_put(file_path, topic):
    print(file_path)
    print(topic)
    call(["/usr/local/hadoop-2.5.1/bin/hadoop fs -put", file_path, "/" + topic]
         , shell=True
         , stderr=STDOUT)
```

Here is what I get (note the arguments are not null):

```
avro/hdfs_1_2014-11-05.avro
hdfs
-put: Not enough arguments: expected 1 but got 0
Usage: hadoop fs [generic options] -put [-f] [-p] <localsrc> ... <dst>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `shell=True`, the `args` is supposed to contain a single string to run in the shell.  You can simply remove `shell=True` and fix your command a bit:

```
check_call(["/usr/local/hadoop-2.5.1/bin/hadoop", "fs", "-put", file_path, "/" + topic]
    , stderr=STDOUT)
```

I changed it to use `check_call` because that's the easy way to check for errors.

Comment: I now get this error: ```FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/local/hadoop-2.5.1/bin/hadoop fs -put'
```

Comment: It does exist though: (venv)bash-4.1# /usr/local/hadoop-2.5.1/bin/hadoop fs -put      
-put: Not enough arguments: expected 1 but got 0
Usage: hadoop fs [generic options] -put [-f] [-p] <localsrc> ... <dst>

Comment: @JohnDoe: I think you neglected to split up the command like I did.  Please read my answer carefully and compare with your code.

Comment: Thanks, missed that, everything is working swell now

Answer (score 1):

You are misusing the shell=True option.

When True, the command is passed to the shell as it is. You do not need to break it into a list.

```
def hdfs_put(file_path, topic):
    print(file_path)
    print(topic)
    call("/usr/local/hadoop-2.5.1/bin/hadoop fs -put " + file_path + " /" + topic
          , shell=True
          , stderr=STDOUT)
```

Or if you want to have arguments as a list, then you will have to drop the Shell=True:

```
def hdfs_put(file_path, topic):
    print(file_path)
    print(topic)
    call(["/usr/local/hadoop-2.5.1/bin/hadoop", "fs", "-put", file_path,  "/" + topic]
         , stderr=STDOUT)
```